# Difference between strchr and strpbrk

Tags: c, string, stdio

What is the difference between `strchr()` and `strpbrk()`. I couldn't find any difference between those.

`strpbrk()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
        char str1[30] = "New Delhi is awesome city", str2[10] = "an";
        char *st;
        st = strpbrk(str1, str2);
        printf("%s"st);
        return 0;
}
```

output: `awesome city`

`strchr()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
        char str1[] = "New Delhi is awesome city", ch = 'a';
        char *chpos;
        chpos = strchr(str1, ch);
        if(chpos)
                printf("%s",chpos);
        return 0;
}
```

output: `awesome city`

Comment: In the first case, try using two characters that are both in the string to search, such as `"wa"`

Comment: They are giving the same output because "a" appears before "n" in `str1`. In fact, "n" doesn't appear in `str1` at all. Try setting `str2` to "as" and you will see it gives different output.

Comment: "... couldn't find any difference between those." --> yet code calls one with `char *` and the other with an `int`.  Hmm.

Comment: Though they may seem cryptic at first, `man strchr` and `man strpbrk` (in fact all the man pages) do a wonderful job explaining the use, operation, return and error reporting as well as the parameter list (useful in assembly programming as well) for each of the functions in the C library.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is clear. From [`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) and [`strpbrk()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strpbrk.3.html):

```
char *strpbrk(const char *s, const char *accept);

       The strpbrk() function locates the first occurrence in the string s
       of any of the bytes in the string accept.


char *strchr(const char *s, int c);

       The strchr() function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of
       the character c in the string s.
```

Basically, `strpbrk()` allows you to specify multiple chars to be searched.
In your example, both `strchr()` and `strpbrk()` both stop after finding the char `'a'` but that doesn't mean they do the same thing!